# swap all instances of two characters in std::string

Tags: c++, string, swap

```
std::string str = "This/is/some/rando\\mly/genera\\ted/path";

std::cout << magical_swap(str, '/', '\\');
```

Output:

```
This\\is\\some\\rando/mly\\genera/ted\\path
```

I can surely do this:

```
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), '/', '#');  // additional assumption: # must not occur anywhere in a string
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), '\\', '/');
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), '#', '\\');
```

Does not look like a proper way to swap characters. Has a weakness (additional assumption), might be slow. How do I go about this?

Comment: I would just write a loop.

Comment: Writing a loop is always a possibility.  I was thinking about maybe STL/Boost solutions? Something really efficient

Comment: The standard library algorithms aren't generally more efficient than a correctly implemented loop, they're just an easy way of ensuring the "correctly implemented" bit. If you're doing something unusual you are often better off just writing your own loop rather than trying to shoehorn your desired behaviour from the standard algorithms

Comment: Let the compiler do its optimizations. If you don't like using loops directly, you can of course use `std::transform` with a lambda as well, in which case it will offer you parallel execution policies if you think that this is really necessary for your use case. For path names like you are showing here it isn't.